# Git Committing unwanted files

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project using webStorm IDE and I started a new project. I created a new repository on githu using the User Interface. Then I changed my remote url to my new repo by using the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

After that I checked my remote url like so:

```
git remote -v
```

This confirmed that my new remote url belonged to my new repo. 
After that I used the following command to commit my code:

```
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

**The issue:**

The commit was successful but it added unwanted files. It added a folder of my previous project and when I ran `git status` almost all my files on my desktop were showing as `untracked files`.

How can I solve this issue so only my new project files are committed?

**Edit:**

Step 1: Create Repo Online

[image]

Step 2: Change Remote Url in webStorm

Step 3: Code App

Step 4: Commit App to new repo

Comment: So you already had files on your disk that you wanted to put on the Github repo? Also what do you mean by "unwated"? You staged and committed all files under that directory, isn't that what you want?

Comment: I feel that something is missing here.  Normally you clone a GitHub repo, do some work, then push.  To create a new repo from scratch you would use `git init`, but you have done neither of these.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated my question with steps I took. Hope this helps. Please let me know if I did something wrong. Thank you!

Comment: OK...if you created a new repo on GitHub, then the first step should be _cloning_ that repo.  You don't tell what files go in the repo at first, GitHub does.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah okay. Apologies I'm new to this. Can you tell me what are the correct steps involved?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/).  The usual workflow is that everything syncs against GitHub.  Initially, GitHub tells you what files are in the repo.  After cloning, you may add/delete files, but then again you sync with GitHub by pushing.  Your current approach might end badly, so you should look at the link.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you! I will have a look at it now but when I create a repo on GitHub I like I showed in the image attached. The repo will be empty there will be no files to clone, am I right? What would I be cloning? Thanks again!

Comment: @Skywalker You wouldn't be cloning anything, but cloning is how your local workspace stays connected to GitHub.  To be very clear, Git does _not_ work with you just throwing random local files to the repo.  You need a `.git` object locally, and cloning will create that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you should follow while creating a new git repo on existing project folder are:

1. Go into the directory containing the project.
2. Type `git init`
3. Type `git add` to add all of the relevant files.
4. Type `git commit`

So when you run the command `git init` it will create a `git` object locally and you can find a `.git` folder inside your project folder. The `commit` you did now is local and you can do whatever you want (like creating new branch, adding more commits etc) which will be local only. Now to push this to a remote repo:

1. Go to github.
2. Log in to your account.
3. Click the new repository button in the top-right.
4. Click the “Create repository” button.

Now as soon as you create new repo you will be on a page where `git` will show you some instructions. In the `Quick Setup` you will find an option for `SSH` or `HTTPS` so copy the desired link you want (if you set up ssh then you won’t have to type your password every time you push things to github) and run in your project folder:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/new_repo
```

and then you can run:

```
git push -u origin master
```

which will push your local repo to remote.

Be sure to run the commands inside your project folder, what you did probably was just changing the `remote-url` inside your existing project which caused you this kind of issues. Wherever you will initialize a `git` repo it will track the changes of the whole folder. So create a new `git` object for each project separately.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the first time in my life git has made sense! THANK YOU!!! Its worked. You are awesome.